# insert data using labmda expression

Tags: entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have a insert sp

```
create procedure sp_insert_services
@Service_Type nvarchar(50),
@Frequency nvarchar(50),

as
insert INTO tbl_fl_Master_List 
(Service_Type,Frequency)
values
(@Service_Type,
@Frequency)
```

now how i write this through lambda expression,linq to sql and EF?

i tried this but this show error

```
 var insert = insertt.tbl_fl_Master_List();
            if(insertt!=null)
            {
                insertt.tbl_fl_Master_List.Add();
            }
            insertt.SaveChanges();
```

Error   8   Non-invocable member 'chart_project.Track_Data.tbl_fl_Master_List' cannot be used like a method.
Error   9   No overload for method 'Add' takes 0 arguments

and also i try this

```
public static string Insert_master_services(string Service_Type,string Frequency)
        {
            Data insertt=new Data();
            tbl_fl_Master_List t = new tbl_fl_Master_List();
            t.Service_Type = Service_Type;
            t.Frequency = Frequency;
            insertt.SaveChanges();

        }
```

Comment: This is tantamount to asking 'How do I use Entity Framework'. I assume you are taking the Database First approach as you have an existing sp. Have you generated a databse model yet?

Comment: @HuseinRoncevic check update

Comment: @ste-fu yes i generate model and i add all sp's and tables